# Excel VBA to update an SQL date field

Tags: sql, vba

I'm trying up date an SQL table (Date field) with a date cell in excel and getting an error

> Error #-2147217913: Operand type clah int is incompatible with Date

Connection to the database is fine.

This is the code i'm using

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
On Error GoTo FormLoadError
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sConnString As String
    Dim FromDate As Date
    Dim ToDate As Date
    Dim FromNumber As String
 
    Sheet2.Range("a2:zz9999").ClearContents
 
    ' Create the connection string.
    sConnString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=SQL;" & _
                  "Initial Catalog=M2MTECLIVE;" & _
                  "Integrated Security=SSPI;"
      
    ' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    
     ' Open the connection and execute.
    conn.Open sConnString
    FromDate = Worksheets("Parameters").Range("b4")   'Cell be contains a date in the format YYYY-MM-DD
    Set rs = conn.Execute("update dbo.M2MDates set FD = " & FromDate)
    conn.Close
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: According to the following link, the date should be enclosed between single quotes : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883448/vba-variable-in-sql-date-query

Comment: Thank for you for the edit Parfait :-)

Comment: Adding the single quotes worked, but not it updates as a European date (i.e. '01/06/2021'  becomes '06/01/2021' in SQL, but progress ....)

Comment: Format the date as YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using ADO parameters via ADO command object which avoids need of concatenating and punctuating values to SQL statement:

```vb
conn.Open sConnString

' PREPARED STATEMENT WITH QMARKS ?
strSQL = "update dbo.M2MDates set FD = ?"
FromDate = Worksheets("Parameters").Range("b4") 

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CommandText = strSQL
    .CommandType = adCmdText

    '  BIND DATE PARAMETER
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("date_prm", adDate, adParamInput, , FromDate)

    '  EXECUTE ACTION QUERY (NO RECORDSET)
    .Execute
End With

conn.Close
Set cmd = Nothing: Set conn = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks - I did not know VBA could parameterize SQL. Is there a way to have multiple parameters? e.g., `SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE id = ? AND type = ?`  If you can point me towards documentation, I'd appreciate it. I already +1 but I can create a new question as well if you'd like.

Comment: There are many SO posts about parameterization in VBA. Nearly every modern programming language have libraries  like ADO that support this recommended method to run SQL at application layer. Start with [SO search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvba%5D+ado+parameter) or Google/Bing, etc. With ADO, for each qmark (`?`) in SQL, add a corresponding `.Parameters.Append` line.

Comment: Thank you @Parfait. When I took over maintenance of some VBA for internal network queries years ago, it was unparameterized. While I have learned a lot since including parameterization, I never put it together that _of course_ VBA would be able to parameterized. If my goal were not to try to port some of these data retrievals to more dashboard like implementations such as [tag:Tableau], I would go forward with this. Thank you again.