# VBA query data containing today's date in a column

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to write a query statement in VBA to extract data from DB2. One of the columns in DAILY_REPORT table is DATE which has the format '5/20/2020  7:55:01 AM'. I am interested in extracting data corresponding to today's date without hours. Below gives me the results i need but date has to be hard typed. How do I make the query dynamic? Thinking of using `GETDATE()` function.

```
   Sub Report()


   Dim NSQL As String
   Dim conn As Object
   Dim rstRecordset As Object

   Const connPath As String = "DSN=;UID=;PWD=;DBALIAS="
   Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
   conn.Open connPath
   
   NSQL = ""
   NSQL = NSQL & "SELECT TECH,ID,MY_DATE FROM DAILY_REPORT WHERE cast(MY_DATE as date)= '2021-07-14'"
   
Set rstRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
   rstRecordset.Open _
       Source:=NSQL, _
       ActiveConnection:=conn, _
       CursorType:=adOpenStatic, _
       LockType:=adLockReadOnly, _
       Options:=adCmdText
   
   With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add( _
           Connection:=rstRecordset, _
           Destination:=Range("A1"))
       .FieldNames = True
       .RowNumbers = False
       .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
       .PreserveFormatting = True
       .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
       .BackgroundQuery = True
       .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
       .SavePassword = True
       .SaveData = True
       .AdjustColumnWidth = True
       .RefreshPeriod = 0
       .PreserveColumnInfo = True
       .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
   End With


rstRecordset.Close
Set rstRecordset = Nothing
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing

Sheets("Data").Visible = True

Call SaveAsCSV_Data

End Sub
```

Thanks all for the help.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What version of db2 are you using?

Comment: The question was more like have you tried something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883448/vba-variable-in-sql-date-query)?

Comment: i am using V11.1

Comment: Edited the post to show what i have done thus far

Comment: What is the meaning of  `NSQL = ""    NSQL = NSQL & ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Understanding that you are casting the unformatted date correctly, you could try CURRENT DATE:

```
WHERE cast(MY_DATE as date)= CURRENT DATE
```

In case your cast doesn't work, you can use the functions [TO_DATE()](https://www.educba.com/db2-to_date/) + [DATE()](https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/db2/docs/content/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000784.html):

```
WHERE 
  DATE(TO_DATE(MY_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM')) = CURRENT DATE
```